# Count the number of new records for a given date only if they are new

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1111

I am trying to count the number of new records for a given date only if the date of the record is the min(date) for the record owner. Here is the query I am trying to run:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM user_total_spends 
 WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id 
                     FROM user_total_spends 
                    WHERE MIN(DATE(date_posted)) = '2012-02-07')
   AND merchant_location_id = '4f39b201-4a50-40ff-9cdf-cec51506eaf2' 
   AND date_posted = '2012-02-07';
```

Basically I am trying to say, if this is the first date this user/merchant is encountered, count it as a new user for this merchant.

When I run this I get a `Invalid use of group function` error. What am I missing?

Comment: Instead of `WHERE min(date(date_posted)) = '2012-02-07'` try `HAVING  min(date(date_posted)) = '2012-02-07'`

Comment: Post the solution so I can mark it as the answer. That worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must use `HAVING` to filter a condition for a group of record or an aggregate function, so Instead of `WHERE min(date(date_posted)) = '2012-02-07'` try `HAVING min(date(date_posted)) = '2012-02-07'`

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
 SELECT count(*) FROM user_total_spends 
    WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM user_total_spends GROUP BY user_id HAVING min(date(date_posted)) = '2012-02-07')
    AND merchant_location_id = '4f39b201-4a50-40ff-9cdf-cec51506eaf2' AND 
    date_posted = '2012-02-07';
```

Comment: @J Cooper : Noted. Thanks... Corrected now